# Proof that ratio of sample means converges to expectation of ratio

Tags: statistics, random-variables, estimation, probability-limit-theorems

Considering two random variables $X$ and $Y$.

I have seen stated in a number of places that $\frac{\overline{x}}{\overline{y}}$ is a consistent estimator for $E(\frac{x}{y})$ "under weak assumptions".

What assumptions are necessary?

Any proofs of the consistency would also be greatly welcomed.

Comment: One would expect that in general $\bar x \bar y$ is a consistent estimator for $Ex/Ey$, and that in general $Ex/y \ne Ex/Ey$.

Comment: @kimchilover -- are you saying that the product of sample averages is a consistent estimator for the ratio of expectations?!

Comment: Agree with @kimchilover (typo notwithstanding) that this is not true as you stated it under any general assumptions. Maybe include your sources and exactly what they said.

Comment: Maybe you have seen that $\frac{\Bbb E(X)}{\Bbb E(Y)}$ is a first order approximation of $\Bbb E\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)$

Comment: It appears I read the sources incorrectly, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not generally true; it's not clear that any set of assumptions that could reasonably called *weak* will do to make it true.

e.g. consider an extremely simple example -- iid $X$ and $Y$ taking the values $1$ and $2$ with equal probability.

Then as $n\to\infty$, $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ converge to a constant, $1.5$ and the ratio will converge to $1$ via Slutsky.

However $E(\frac{X}{Y})$ is $\frac98$.

Note that for $Y$ a positive variate with nonzero variance, $E(\frac{1}{Y})>\frac{1}{E(Y)}$. Consequently, when $X$ has positive expectation, $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Y$ is positive and has nonzero variance, $E(\frac{X}{Y})>\frac{E(X)}{E(Y)}$.

I don't think any set of conditions I'd reasonably call weak would exclude all of those cases (and that's just a subset of the cases where it's not going to work).